# Can't figure out why im getting null values in my array print statement

Tags: java

I am loading in an array, getting the sum from the values around it, then assigning a string value to a new array based on what the sum/6 is. So when I run through it every single array value should have something in it, not a null. However, when I print my array I get the expected output (based on an example I have been given), with the exception of random "null"'s within my print statement. I can't figure out why these null statements are coming up. Here is my code along with an example of what is printing out, and what should be printing out.

```
public static void displaymap(int maparray[][])
  {
    String mapicons[][] = new String [22][32];
    int col=1;
    int row=1;
    int row2=0;
    int col2=0;
    double sum[]= new double [704];
    for(int i=0;i<704;i++)
    {
      if(col ==33)
      {
        col = 1;
        row++;
        if(row==24)
        {
          row=0;
          col=0;
          break;
        }
      }
      sum[i]=(double)(maparray[row][col]+maparray[row-1][col]+maparray[row+1][col]+maparray[row][col-1]+maparray[row][col+1])/6;
      col++;
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n",sum[i]);
      if(sum[i]>9)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" #";
        }
      if(sum[i]>8&&sum[i]<9)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" *";
        }
      if(sum[i]>7&&sum[i]<8)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" +";
        }
      if(sum[i]>6&&sum[i]<7)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" .";
        }
      if(sum[i]<6)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]="  ";
        }
      col2++;
      if(col2 ==32)
        {
          col2 = 0;
          row2++;
         }
    }
    for(row=0;row<22;row++)
      {
        for(col=0;col<32;col++)
          System.out.printf("%s",mapicons[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
      }
  }
```

This is what is being outputted:

```
                              null         .                      
        null     #                                          null    
      null .                     +                           . . +
 .     +null                  null   . + .                       .  
         .                         .                            
                                   +     .       .null        null  
                             +             .      null .          
 +                                       .null +     .            
               .        null               . . .    null            
                           .                       .       . .  
                                                 .    null +      
                                            nullnull                
                   .         .                 .       . . .    
     .                                                  nullnull    
                                                       .null      
null     .         .             .                                
 .   .           .           +   .                      null      
  null                          null                                
             .                                 .                
     .               +                           . .            
            null     .         . .                     .   .    null
                                       .             . * . .
```

And this is what should be outputted:

```
                                       .                      
             #                                              
       .                     +                           . . +
 .     +                     . + .                       .  
         .                         .                            
                                   +     .       .          
                             +             .       .          
 +                                       . +     .            
               .                       . . .                
                           .                       .      . .  
                                                 .     +      

                   .         .                 .       . . .    
     .                                                      
                                                       .      
     .         .             .                                
 .   .           .           +   .                            

             .                                 .                
     .               +                           . .            
                .         . .                     .   .    
                                       .             . * . .
```

So as you can see it is essentially the same thing minus the nulls, and certain characters would format properly if there wasn't nulls taking up space.

Comment: Presumably you're trying to print something that has a value of null.  Use a debugger to figure out why.

Comment: Maybe there is a case you are not handling with your `if` statement. Why don't you use an `if-else if-else` structure? Can you give the `maparray` you are using as paremeter?, so we can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some edge cases your code can't handle. No conditions are `true`, thus `mapicons` is not totally filled. Then, `null` values are printed out.

For example, when `sum` is exactly equal to 8, 7 or 6.

Try with the following code:

```
public static void displaymap(int maparray[][])
  {
    String mapicons[][] = new String [22][32];
    int col=1;
    int row=1;
    int row2=0;
    int col2=0;
    double sum[]= new double [704];
    for(int i=0;i<704;i++)
    {
      if(col ==33)
      {
        col = 1;
        row++;
        if(row==24)
        {
          row=0;
          col=0;
          break;
        }
      }
      sum[i]=(double)(maparray[row][col]+maparray[row-1][col]+maparray[row+1][col]+maparray[row][col-1]+maparray[row][col+1])/6;
      col++;
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n",sum[i]);
      if(sum[i]>=9)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" #";
        }
      else if(sum[i]>=8)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" *";
        }
      else if(sum[i]>=7)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" +";
        }
      else if(sum[i]>=6)
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]=" .";
        }
      else
        {
          mapicons[row2][col2]="  ";
        }
      col2++;
      if(col2 ==32)
        {
          col2 = 0;
          row2++;
         }
    }
    for(row=0;row<22;row++)
      {
        for(col=0;col<32;col++)
          System.out.printf("%s",mapicons[row][col]);
        System.out.println();
      }
  }
```

**EDIT:** You can even use `if/elseif` instead of `if` chain.

Comment: This worked, can't believe I didn't think about it, only thing different is I set it <= the larger number in each if statement to keep the values I needed being correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue has to deal with the < and > when setting the mapicons values. You have cases for > 8 and < 8, but nothing for == 8 (for example).

Try this small change :

```
if(sum[i]>9)
{
     mapicons[row2][col2]=" #";
}
if(sum[i]>=8&&sum[i]<9)
{
     mapicons[row2][col2]=" *";
}
if(sum[i]>=7&&sum[i]<8)
{
     mapicons[row2][col2]=" +";
}
if(sum[i]>=6&&sum[i]<7)
{
     mapicons[row2][col2]=" .";
}
if(sum[i]<6)
{
     mapicons[row2][col2]="  ";
}
```