# Printing String[] produces random null values, unsure why it's happening

Tags: java, arrays, string

I tried finding this problem on this site, and the closest similar thread was this:

[Can't figure out why im getting null values in my array print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735210/cant-figure-out-why-im-getting-null-values-in-my-array-print-statement)

Basically, I have an instance variable array of Strings taking words from a dictionary.txt file whenever its method is called (I have a separate main method). I have it set up to create a new array with double the capacity whenever it reaches its limit:

```
public String[] lengthN (int n) {
    /*String[] output = new String[1000];*/
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        if (i == output.length) {
            increaseSize();
        }   
        if (word.length() != n) {

        }
        if (word.length() == n) {
            output[i] = word;
            /*System.out.println(output[i]);
            System.out.println(i);*/
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(output[j]); //for testing purposes,returns random null values
    }   
    return output;
}

public void increaseSize() {
      String[] temp = new String[output.length + 1000];
      for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
          temp[i] = output[i];
          output = temp;
      }    
}
```

Thankfully, it actually runs and prints out this list. However, in addition to these words, it appears as though large chunks of my list are replaced with null values.

The output itself is too long to post here (with >10000 elements or so), but essentially it is along the lines of

```
aardvark
null
null
null
null
//lots of null values dispersed throughout
vindicate
vineyards
vintagers
null
null
null
null
```

If anyone could help point me to a way to fix this problem, I'd be incredibly appreciative! (Apologies if I didn't explain well, first time posting here).

Comment: First of all - please use a better data structure. For example, a list. Second your problem is in the increseSize() method, you are saving the array in the loop. Try moving it outside the loop.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr Thanks for the comment. Just wanted to know what you meant by using a better data structure? I apologize, I'm still a beginner at coding in Java (and in programming in general).

Comment: Basically an array in Java is a fixed size. Yes, you can create a large array but in essence you are wasting space/time by doing so. Using something like a List will mean your array is always the exact size for the number of items you have. I might look up LinkedLists while you are at it for a better understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
public void increaseSize() {
      String[] temp = new String[output.length + 1000];
      for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
          temp[i] = output[i];
          output = temp; // <-- here
      }    
}
```

you are setting the `output` array variable to the `temp` array inside your loop. On subsequent iterations through the loop, `output` and `temp` are referencing the same array, so `temp[i] = output[i]` does nothing. Presumably you meant something like this:

```
public void increaseSize() {
      String[] temp = new String[output.length + 1000];
      for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
          temp[i] = output[i];
      }
      // Once the loop is finished, and the whole contents have been copied, use the `temp` array as the new `output`.
      output = temp;
}
```

That should work pretty much the same as just having:

```
output = Arrays.copyOf(output, output.length+1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @khelwood! Now that it's been pointed out it makes a lot of sense. For loops trip me up a lot


edit: I JUST read about using copyOf in the API documentation. If only I waited a couple more minutes! Thanks though.